# Parsing JSON in PHP "stdClass could not be converted to string" error

Tags: php, parsing

I had this string:

```
{\"lat\":37.790388261934424,\"lng\":-122.46047996826172},{\"lat\":37.789608231530124,\"lng\":-122.46344112701416}
```

Then thanks to the help of StackOverflowers, I did this to strip the slashes:

```
$markers = stripslashes($markers);
```

Then I tried to add the outside brackets which seemed to be needed by the decode function

```
$markers = json_decode('['.$markers.']');
```

Was that the right way to go about it?  Then I tried to do this:

```
foreach($markers as $key => $value) 
{
    $some_string = $some_string.' ( '.$value.' ) ';
}
```

Which game me this error:

```
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

But what I really need is to extract the lat/lng values into $lat , $lng variables.  Could someone suggest to me how to fix the error I am getting and put the values into the variables?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try...

```
foreach($markers as $marker) 
{
     $some_string .= '('.$marker->lat.','.$marker->lng.')';
}
```

Result...

```
(37.7903882619,-122.460479968)(37.7896082315,-122.463441127)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($markers as $key => $value) 
{
    // $value is object with lat and lng properties 
    $some_string = $some_string.' ( lat:'.$value->lat.' ) ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was something that puzzled me too, why is json_decode() returning the data encapsulated in objects?

It turns out that all arrays in Javascript are considered objects, hence json_decode() returns them as objects of the PHP stdClass. Try to do print_r() on the $marker to see how it is structured.

Answer (score 0):

This here works

```
var json = JSON.parse(<?php echo "'" . stripslashes($_POST['json']) . "'" ?>);
```

Comment: This really doesn't address question better than any of the other answers do.